# Editor and Terminal often stop working when switching among Pycharm projects

Tags: pycharm

In the latest two versions of PyCharm I have noticed that sometimes when switching to a project it is not possible to type in any new content - either in editor panels or in the Terminal sessions.  Other open projects may be switched to and are working. But even after switching to and from that suspect project it still is non-responsive.

The Terminal Cursor shows it is not focused (even when attempting to switch to it) and the editor does not show the edit cursor even when the editor panel has the focus:

[image]

I thought maybe it's indexing or something like that, but that behavior just happened and in this case nothing has been done in the project for hours.

After a few minutes and jumping around in Pycharm as well as other applications and then returning to the project it now has a normal edit cursor in both the editor panel and [when switching to it] the Terminal panel.

Some things I have tried (and do not help):

- restarting `PyCharm`
- invalidating caches
- deleting `PyCharm` project / recreating it
- increasing memory available
- installing new version of `Pycharm`

Has anyone else experienced this and found a fix or workaround? I am on PyCharm Pro 2022.3.1 on `macOS Ventura 13.1`.

**Update**  I have restarted `Pycharm` and this non-responsiveness is happening across *all* projects presently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has changed from occasionally to always afaict.  The only fix - inconvenient as it is - seems to be to switch to another *application* in between switching among `Pycharm` windows.

*Update* Actually that switching does not work either. This is an unresolved issue

**Another update** This behavior is consistent across multiple recent versions of `pycharm`. The project switcher is broken.  A workaround is to view all projects via the `Window` top level menu. That's slower but works.